# What do the original seven main-series books say about how Muggle technology and magic interact?

Tags: harry-potter, magical-theory

I'm pretty sure that it's established that the reason why we don't see modern technology being used in the series is because magic and Muggle technology just don't agree somehow. However, I'm confident that this is all largely in the extended lore. What do the original seven books - i.e. *Philosopher's Stone* to *Deathly Hallows* - say about this?

Comment: It seems like somebody who found out how to combine magic and technology would easily rule the world.  Robots who didn't rust, self-healed, were animated like the Hogwarts statues, and you only had to make one and then duplicate it by magic; guns that fired bullets which right before impact transfigured into bombs; TV broadcasted mind control.  It would make a great sequel book series.  Maybe even a disgruntled Arthur Weasley.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From chapter 28 of Goblet of Fire (page 475 in my UK first edition) Hermione tells us:

> "All those substitutes for magic Muggles use - electricity, and computers and radar, and all those things - they all go haywire around Hogwarts, there's too much magic in the air."

The implication is certainly that it's the mere presence of strong magic which causes technology to play up. Not that this is always the case, though; looking at examples such as Mr. Weasley's Ford Anglia in Chamber of Secrets, we can see that magic can also be used in harmony with technology. Possibly certain spells are needed to counteract the usual bad effect magic has on technology.